# Avro GenericRecord cannot be cast to Java.util.Collection issue

Tags: avro

I am quite new at Avro. I got an Exception at line "writer.write (datum, encoder); " in following code when I try to serialized my data.

```
        byte[] byteData = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try
        {             
            DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);  
            Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);  
            writer.write(datum, encoder);  
            encoder.flush();  
            byteData = out.toByteArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO log error
            throw new RuntimeException (e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                out.close(); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException (e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

        return byteData;
```

My Avro Schema is

```
{"type":"record",
"name":"MainSchema",
"namespace":"****",
"fields":[{"name":"GenericName","type":"string"},
        {"name":"DataCarrier",
         "type":{"type":"array",
                "items":{
                            "type":"record",
                            "name":"SubSchema",
                            "fields":[{"name":"DataValue",
                                        "type":{"type":"map","values":"string"}}]}}}]}
```

The error message is as below: (To me, it looks like the avro writer doesn't like that array of GenericRecord data)

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lorg.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord; cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a UTF-8 to String conversion issue. Solved.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10421220)

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci: Looks like this is an answer, and I'll edit and remove the *thanks*.